# Disable html tooltip on d3 bubble chart?

Tags: html, d3.js

If you look at this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

When you mouseover the circle text, there is an html tooltip that pops up. Is there any way to disable this?

I thought using css would resolve the issue:

```
body {
   font-family: Trebuchet, sans-serif;
   color: black;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: normal;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
 }
```

but no luck.

Comment: Just run `d3.selectAll("title").remove()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tooltip is shown by the browser based on the `title` attribute. If you remove the line of JavaScript that adds this, the tooltip will no longer appear.

Comment: Could I resolve this using something like: $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title') bound to a mouseover event?